# How to add point to an existing score value that works after refreshing the bowser

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, web-storage

I have an issue with adding a point to the existing/old score value after I refresh the web page. Instead of adding a point to the existing/old score, it replaces it, which means if there's an existing/old score already, it will reset and start from 1 again. I don't want that. I want it continues.

Here's my current code, the localStorage code is on the bottom:

```
function addPhoto(data, mode) {
    // DATA
    let userName = data.uniqueId;
    let userAvatar = data.profilePictureUrl;
    let word = ['Nice going','That’s better than ever','That’s first class work','I’m impressed','Nothing can stop you now','Well done','Good job','You did it','That’s the way','You rock','I knew you could do it','Keep up the good work','That’s clever','Way to go','Outstanding','Tremendous','Fantastic','You are amazing','No one can beat you','You are the chosen one'];
    let words = word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)];

    if (mode == "winner") {
    wins[userName] = wins[userName] || 0
    wins[userName]++
        addContent(
                `<div style="text-align:center;font-size: .8rem;">
                    <div style='padding-bottom:.25rem;color:#1881FF;'> `+ words + `</div>
                    <div style='padding-bottom:.5rem;font-weight: bold;color:#20B601;'>`+ userName + ` ❗</div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="`+ userAvatar + `" style="width:135px;height:135px;border-radius: 30%;border: 1px solid #20B601;box-shadow: 0 0 7px 1px #20B601;"/>
                        <span style='color:#EA0C0C; font-weight: bold;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wins: x`+ wins[userName] + `</span>
                    </div>
            </div>`
        );
}

    // Set
    $("#lastWinner").html(`<div class="lastWinPopUp winnerpopup">
                            <p>Winner:</p>
                            </br>`+ userName + `
                            </br></br><img src="`+ userAvatar + `" style="width:80px;height:80px;border-radius: 10%;box-shadow: 0 0 7px 1px #000000;"/>
                            </br></br>Win streak:<p id="score"></p>
                          </div>`
                          ); 
                          //<span style='color:#EA0C0C; font-weight: bold;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wins: x`+ wins[userName] + `</span>

    // Sound
    playSound(3);

    const username = userName;
    const score = wins[userName];
    localStorage.setItem(username, score)

    var existing = localStorage.getItem(username);

    var data = existing ? existing + score : score;

    localStorage.setItem(username, data);
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(username);
}
```

The result from this current code is:

After refreshing the page, it will replace the existing/old score, and start again from 1 point. As you can see I tried adding the `var existing` an attempt to add a point to the existing/old score.

But instead of adding 1 point, it adds number `1` literally next to the current value which will become `11`(becomes 1 because it still replaces the existing/old score), and becomes `22`, `33`, and so on as it adds more points.

Could anyone modify the code for me?

Comment: FYI: within those `template literal strings` in your function you do not need to break from the literal - you can wrap the variables (or other js commands) like this `${VARNAME}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned, the values within the store will be strings so cast the value to a number and then use `++` to add

```
let username='teddybear';

var existing = localStorage.getItem(username);
if( !isNaN( existing ) ){
    var data = parseInt( existing );
}else{
    var data=0;
}
data++;
localStorage.setItem( username, data );
```

---

The problem with the original code is that you explicitly set the localStorage back to a default value on each page load/reload.

This piece:

```
const username = userName;
const score = wins[userName];
localStorage.setItem(username, score)
```

Instead of doing that, check whether the value held is null or `NaN` and proceed from there. This is a slightly modified version of the above with some example data

```
// hard-coded.... for demo only
let wins={
    'teddybear':2,
    'fungus':0,
    'homer':3,
    'orinnocco':7
};
let username='teddybear';// hard-coded.... for demo only


var existing = localStorage.getItem( username );
if( existing!=null && !isNaN( existing ) ){
    var data = parseInt( existing );
}else{
    var data=wins[ username ];
}
data++;
localStorage.setItem( username, data );
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I suppose I've figured out how to add value to the existing score, thanks to everyone's help. However, that just solved one of my issues. I still require assistance on the other issue, after refreshing the page, it replaces the existing score instead of continuing to add a new score to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the **localStorage stores the values ​​as a string**, and when you perform a concatenation operation on a string it simply adds another character to the string, there are two ways to fix the problem:

1. You need to convert the value to a number according to the calculation with `parseInt`

```
    var existing = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(username));
    
    var data = existing ? existing + score : score;
```

2. Or, in the connection operation, you will put the element that is a
   number first, that way the connection operation will automatically
   convert the value that came from the local storage into a number
   during the calculation

```
    var existing = localStorage.getItem(username);
    
    var data = existing ? score + existing: score;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried your suggestion. The result on your first suggestion is: first, it still replaces the existing score after refreshing the browser. Secondly, the point becomes 2 points per win so like 2, 4, 6, and so on. The result on your second suggestion is: it does exactly the same as my existing code and it still replaces the existing value after refreshing the page.

Comment: @rich I'm missing parts of your code to answer for sure, but it seems because you initially have `localStorage.setItem(username, score)`
 (seems to be unnecessary and does your problem)

Answer (score 0):

Storage stores values as a string, so before doing the number manipulation, you'll have to convert it to a number.

```
var existing = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(username), 10);
var data = existing ? existing + score : score;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried your suggestion. The result is, first, it still replaces the existing score after refreshing the browser. Secondly, the point becomes 2 points per win so like 2, 4, 6, and so on.

Comment: I didn't really go through your code regarding a refresh because the assumption was that you'll take care of it yourself anyway, the main problem seemed like the values you were storing were not storing correctly and I provided a solution for that. It would have been nice if you posted a working code snippet for others to see what you're actually trying to achieve and what is wrong at the moment. :)